# How can I create an iterator that repeats multiple values infinitely?

Tags: iterator, rust

Using [repeat](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/fn.repeat.html) I can create an iterator which repeats one element. But how can I repeat multiple values infinitely?
For example:

```
let repeat_1 = repeat(1); // 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
let repeat_123 = repeat([1, 2, 3]); // 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, ... // or similar
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use [`.cycle()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cycle) like this:

```
fn main() {
    let values = [1, 2, 3];
    let repeat_123 = values.iter().cloned().cycle();
    for elt in repeat_123.take(10) {
        println!("{}", elt)
    }
}
```

It works on any *iterator* that can be cloned (the *iterator*, not its elements).

Please note that the [`.cloned()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) adaptor is incidental! It translates the by-reference iterator elements of the slice's iterator into values.

A simpler way to write this particular sequence is:

```
let repeat_123 = (1..4).cycle();
```

Answer (score 5):

Found it out:
One can also `repeat` arrays, tuples or slices (depending on the needs).

For example:

```
let repeat_123 = std::iter::repeat([1, 2, 3]); // [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], ...
```

This iterator is nested, however, to flatten it, use [flatmap](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IteratorExt.html#tymethod.flat_map)

```
let pattern = &[1, 2, 3];
let repeat_123_flat = std::iter::repeat(pattern).flat_map(|x| x.iter());
```